# UIPageControl and delay in appearing

Tags: iphone, ios, uipagecontrol

How do I make an instance of `UIPageControl` appear immediately? (I have set `defersCurrentPageDisplay` to `NO`.)

I have an instance of `UIPageControl` which is configured (number of pages, current page and then updated) when my view appears. However there is a short, fixed delay before it appears to the user. I'd like it to appear right away.

Otherwise it's working fine.

Comment: Are you configuring it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: I've tried in both and I still have the problem. I assume that the page control is supposed to appear immediately? (I haven't used this object previously.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is I'm performing a lengthy background process and I've inadvertently and ultimately called `updateCurrentPageDisplay` etc. from this secondary thread. `UIKit` is not thread-safe and blocks this call until it can move it to the main thread, hence the delay.

To solve this, I've subclassed `UIPageControl` creating "wrapper" methods that push calls to `super` onto the main thread. I can then safely forget about this every time I need to speak with my page controls.

For example:

```
- (void) updateCurrentPageDisplay
{
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    if ([UIDevice currentDeviceSupportsGrandCentralDispatch] == YES)
    {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [super updateCurrentPageDisplay];
      });
    }
    else
    {
      [super performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateCurrentPageDisplay)
                              withObject:nil
                           waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the delay issue by adding the UIPageViewController delegate's willTransitionToViewControllers and setting the pageController's index there:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers {
for (MyContentPageViewController *contentController in pendingViewControllers) {
    if ([contentController isKindOfClass:[MyContentPageViewController class]]) {
        NSUInteger newIndex = contentController.pageIndex;
        [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:newIndex];
    }
}
```

Then, to avoid bugs in cases where swipe is not completed, add the following delegate method:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{
if(finished){
    for (MyContentPageViewController *contentController in previousViewControllers) {
        if ([contentController isKindOfClass:[MyContentPageViewController class]]) {
            NSUInteger currentIndex = MIN(MAX(0, contentController.pageIndex), _allPages.count- 1);
            [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentIndex];
        }
    }
} else {
    for (MyContentPageViewController *contentController in previousViewControllers) {
        if ([contentController isKindOfClass:[MyContentPageViewController class]]) {
            NSUInteger currentIndex = MIN(MAX(0, contentController.pageIndex), _allPages.count);
            [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:currentIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

}